# In Android Kotlin, when creating a dialog, the samples I've seen include "_, _ ->" what does that mean or do?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-alertdialog

The tutorial I'm working on gives this code:

```
private fun showFinalScoreDialog() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
        .setTitle(getString(R.string.congratulations))
        .setMessage(getString(R.string.you_scored, viewModel.score))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.exit)) { _, _ ->
            exitGame()
        }
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.play_again)) { _, _ ->
            restartGame()
        }
        .show()
}
```

The tutorial took this moment to explain "trailing lambda syntax", but didn't bother to explain the actual content of the lambda. The part that I'm clueless on is `_, _ ->` what is this? What does it do?

The tutorial says "...the `setNegativeButton()` method takes in two parameters: a String and a function, `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`..."

Comment: Shortly after I posted this, I found the answer [here](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/getting-started-with-dialogs-in-android-kotlin/): _Kotlin simplifies this by allowing us to pass in underscores for unused arguments in the lambda function._

Comment: Good that you could find the answer by yourself. If you could anyway mark my answer as 'accepted' I would be very grateful, thanks :)

Comment: SO forced me to wait, or I'd have accepted it before you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `->` is used for lambda expressions to separate parameters from the function body. The lambda you're writing for both buttons will be invoked when the buttons are clicked. So, the `exitGame` operation will execute when clicking the "NegativeButton", and the `restartGame` operation will execute when clicking the "PositiveButton".

When writing `_` as the parameters, it basically means that you don't care about them, because they won't be used in your function body.